# Minimum size of set intersection

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, discrete-optimization

There was a survey about 5 kinds of common diseases and 100 people took the survey. 72 people have the first kind of disease, and 68, 66, 59, 82 for other 4 diseases respectively. People with **at least 3** diseases took another more in-depth survey.
What is the minimum number of participants who took another survey? Four possible answers are as follows.

A.48

B.49

C.50

D.51

I tried to achieve the answer but was not even close. Here's my reasoning.

Let set $A$ be all the 100 people, i.e., $|A|$=100. And let set $A_i$ be the people who have the $i^{th}$ disease, where $A_i \subset A, i \in \{1,2,3,4,5\} $, $|A_1|$=72, $|A_2|$=68, $|A_3|$=66, $|A_4|$=59 and $|A_5|$=82. Then we want the minimum size of $\bigcup_{i,j,k\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}}^{i \ne j \ne k, i \ne k} A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k$.

Notice that $|A_i \cap A_j| = |A_i| + |A_j| - |A_i \cup A_j| \ge |A_i| + |A_j| - |A|$, so similarly $|A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k| \ge |A_i| + |A_j| + |A_k| - 2|A|$.

So $|\bigcup_{i,j,k\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}}^{i \ne j \ne k, i \ne k} A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k| \ge |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_5| \ge 22$. But it's just a weak conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

$72 + 68 + 66 +59 + 82 = 347$ : Total number (with duplicates) of diseases is 347

$5*48+2*(100-48)=344$ : If only 48 people have more than 2 diseases, maximum total number (with duplicates) of diseases is 344

$344$ is less than $347$, so $48$ is not enough.

$5*49+2*(100-49)=347$

So $49$ should be enough, and it is easy to check that $49$ is enough.

Comment: That seems to be the correct calculation, though is perhaps missing some justifications such as checking $49 \le \min( 72,68, 66, 59, 82 )$

Comment: What does the first two lines mean? Could you please add some explanation? I'm too stupid to get it...

Comment: I have added some explanations for first 2 lines. I hope it is clear enough now.  (Step1) First row 72+68+66+59+82 ... The result of this sum is central ; it is a very important step, do you agree, and do you see the meaning of this sum ?  (Step2) If k is the number of people with more than 2 diseases, 5k+2(100-k) is another important step in the process. Do you see what represents this sum 5k+2(100-k) ?  And k is a possible value only if (step3) 5k+2(100-k)  >= 72+68+66+59+82. Is it clear for you ?

Comment: If k=48, 5k+2(100-k) is less than 72+68+66+59+82 ; so we can be sure that 48 is not enough, at least 49 people have 3 or more diseases. if k=49, 5k+2(100-k) is equal to 72+68+66+59+82, so probably we can find some arrangements, where exactly 49 people have 5 diseases, and 51 remaining have 2 diseases.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó For example you can have $49$ with all five diseases ABCDE, $23$ with just AE, $17$ with just BC, $1$ with just BD, $1$ with just BE, and $9$ with just DE.  Many other patterns would work too

Comment: @DávidLaczkó From my example, you can have $49$ with all five diseases ABCDE, and $23$ with just AE so those with A amount to $49+23=72$ as required

Comment: @Henry & Lourrran While deriving the formula I see now why it meets all the criteria. I removed all my other input from the page to reduce noise. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming, with a nonnegative integer decision variable $x_j$ for each of the $2^5=32$ possible subsets and linear constraints to enforce the given cardinalities.  For your example, the problem is to minimize
$$x_{7} + x_{11} + x_{13} + x_{14} + x_{15} + x_{19} + x_{21} + x_{22} + x_{23} + x_{25} + x_{26} + x_{27} + x_{28} + x_{29} + x_{30} + x_{31}$$
subject to
linear constraints
\begin{align}
x_{1} + x_{3} + x_{5} + x_{7} + x_{9} + x_{11} + x_{13} + x_{15} + x_{17} + x_{19} + x_{21} + x_{23} + x_{25} + x_{27} + x_{29} + x_{31} &= 72 \\                                     
x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{6} + x_{7} + x_{10} + x_{11} + x_{14} + x_{15} + x_{18} + x_{19} + x_{22} + x_{23} + x_{26} + x_{27} + x_{30} + x_{31} &= 68 \\                                     
x_{4} + x_{5} + x_{6} + x_{7} + x_{12} + x_{13} + x_{14} + x_{15} + x_{20} + x_{21} + x_{22} + x_{23} + x_{28} + x_{29} + x_{30} + x_{31} &= 66 \\                                    
x_{8} + x_{9} + x_{10} + x_{11} + x_{12} + x_{13} + x_{14} + x_{15} + x_{24} + x_{25} + x_{26} + x_{27} + x_{28} + x_{29} + x_{30} + x_{31} &= 59 \\                            
x_{16} + x_{17} + x_{18} + x_{19} + x_{20} + x_{21} + x_{22} + x_{23} + x_{24} + x_{25} + x_{26} + x_{27} + x_{28} + x_{29} + x_{30} + x_{31} &= 82 \\                              
\sum_{j=0}^{31} x_j &= 100
\end{align}
The minimum turns out to be $49$, achieved by taking
$$x_6 = 8, 
x_{10} = 1,  
x_{12} = 9, 
x_{17} = 23, 
x_{18} = 10, 
x_{31} = 49,$$
and all other $x_j=0$.

---

It turns out that the linear programming relaxation also has minimum value $49$, and the corresponding dual variables provide a short certificate of optimality as follows.  Let $w_j$ be the Hamming weight of $j$, and let
$\pi_j = (2- w_j \pmod 3)/3$.
Now multiply the first five equality constraints by $1/3$, the last equality constraint by $-2/3$, the lower bounds $x_j \ge 0$ by $\pi_j$, and add everything up, yielding
\begin{align}
&\quad x_{7} + x_{11} + x_{13} + x_{14} + x_{15} + x_{19} + x_{21} + x_{22} + x_{23} + x_{25} + x_{26} + x_{27} + x_{28} + x_{29} + x_{30} + x_{31} \\
&\ge \frac{1}{3}\left(72 + 68 + 66 + 59 + 82\right) - \frac{2}{3} \cdot 100 \\ 
&= 49
\end{align}

Comment: Did you solve it on computer or by hand? Looks like it'll take quite a long time to solve the integer linear programming problem by hand. But I think it's also a good solution. Thanks RobPratt!

Comment: Yes, I used a solver.  It turns out that the linear programming relaxation (obtained by ignoring the integrality of $x_j$) also has minimum value $49$.

Comment: Thanks RobPratt. I searched Wikipedia for Hamming weight but still didn't know the meaning of 'Hamming weight of j'. And what does the magic (2−(mod3))/3 mean by the way?

Comment: The Hamming weight $w_j$ is the number of ones in the binary representation of $j$ (equivalently, the number of elements in the corresponding subset).  For example, $w_7=3$.  The formula for $\pi_j$ is shorthand for $2/3$ if $w_j\in\{0,3\}$, $1/3$ if $w_j\in\{1,4\}$, and $0$ otherwise.